# How can I use order by and group by in Linq Extraction Method and With multiple data?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a person list contains person has a weight, age, city and name property.

Person.cs:

```
 public class Person
{
public int Weight { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set; }
public string Name {get; set;}
public string City {get; set;}
}
```

Program.cs:

```
 List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();

 personList.Add(new Person { Age = 15, Weight = 68, Name = “Dany”, City =”New York”  });
 personList.Add(new Person { Age = 19, Weight = 75, Name = “Dany”, City =”New York” });
 personList.Add(new Person { Age = 17, Weight = 68, Name = “Dany”, City =”New York” });
 personList.Add(new Person { Age = 15, Weight = 55, Name = “Dany”, City =”New York” });
 personList.Add(new Person { Age = 15, Weight = 53, Name = “Dany”, City =”New York” });
 personList.Add(new Person { Age = 17, Weight = 88, Name = “Dany”, City =”New York” });
 personList.Add(new Person { Age = 19, Weight = 45, Name = “Dany”, City =”New York” });
 personList.Add(new Person { Age = 20, Weight = 88, Name = “Dany”, City =”New York” });

 //Grouped person list 
 List<People> GroupedPersonList = new List<People>();

 var GroupedPersonList = personList.GroupBy(x => x.Age , (key,element) =>    new
{
    Age = key,
    Weight = element.Max(c=>c.Weight)
    City = ????,
    Name = ?????
});
```

Elements that should be listed: Grouped by age and each group should be selected with the highest weight.(I want to order this list by age, but the list contains only the weightiest person of that age. Then I will create a new list via this.) The new new list should look like this:

(GroupedPersonList Contents)=>

Age    | Weight |Name  | City

-------|------- |------|--------

15     | 68     |Dany  | New York

17     | 88     |Dany  | New York

19     | 75     |Dany  | New York

20     | 88     |Dany  | New York

```
  foreach (var item in GroupedPersonList)
  {
    string city =  item.City; // Error because No city in list
  }
```

I can group in this way. But I can only use 2 properties (Age and Weight).I also need to assign these parameters. How to assign other parameters? How can I do that in LINQ extraction method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want I believe is this:

```
var GroupedPersonList = personList
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Weight)
    .GroupBy(x=>x.Age)
    .Select(x =>x.First())
    .OrderBy (x => x.Age);
```

What this does is takes your original list and:

- Orders by weight descending.
- Groups by age. These groups will still be ordered by weight descending.
- Selects the first item in each group which because of the ordering will be the highest weight item.
- Orders the resulting list by age which is the desired output.

This assumes that `GroupedPersonList` should be a `List<Person>` though you do have a reference to it being a `List<People>` so I may have misunderstood something. If `People` really is an object then please let us know what it looks like!

Also your final list will be references to the same objects as your original list so if you changed anything on these it would reflect in the original objects. This may or may not be what you want. It does however mean that you have access to every property that is on the Person object without having to set them each individually as you are attempting to do in your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
var GroupedPersonList = personList.GroupBy(x => x.Age, (key, element) =>
{
    var weightiest = element.First(p => p.Weight == element.Max(c => c.Weight));
    return new
            {
                Age = key,
                Weight = weightiest.Weight,
                  City = weightiest.City,
                Name = weightiest.Name
            };
});
```

Comment: a linq function can do more then one line of code if you warp it in {}, just like If or forEach.

first i find the person with the max weight (the first person how has the maw weight) from all of the people with the same age and place that in weightiest.

then i create and return a new object using the age (key) and the  weightiest object properties.

Answer (score 2):

```
var GroupedPersonList = personList.GroupBy(
    x => x.Age,
    (k, x) => x.OrderByDescending(p => p.Weight).First());
```